# Committing changes to the database using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I have a situation where I pull data from a table by date. If no data is supplied for a given date I create a record using default values and display it all to the user. When the user is done manipulating the data I need to commit the changes.

So my question is how do I handle in Entity Framework submitting a table where there could be both updates and adds that need to be done. This is in C# using MVC3 and Entity Framework.

So here's what the data might look like to start,

**Table A**

```
NAME  AGE PHONE_NUM 
Jim   25  555-555-5555 
Jill  48  555-551-5555
```

After the users done with the data it could look like this,

**Table A**

```
NAME  AGE PHONE_NUM
Jim   25  555-555-5555
Jill  28  555-551-5555
Rob   42  555-534-6677
```

How do I commit these changes? My problem is there are both updates and inserts needed?

I've found some code like this but I don't know if it will work in this case.

For adding rows of data

```
entities.TABlEA.AddObject(TableOBJECT);
entities.SaveChanges();
```

or for updating data

```
entities.TABLEA.Attach(entities.TABLEA.Single(t => t.NAME == TableOBJECT.NAME));
entities.TABLEA.ApplyCurrentValues(TableOBJECT);
entities.SaveChanges();
```

Will any of this work or do I need to keep track of whats there and what was added?

Ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More or less you already have the solution. You just need to check if your `Single` call which tries to load the object from the DB has an result or not (use `SingleOrDefault` instead). If the result is `null` you need to insert, otherwise update:

```
foreach (var TableOBJECT in collectionOfYourTableOBJECTsTheUserWorkedWith)
{
    var objectInDB = entities.TABLEA
        .SingleOrDefault(t => t.NAME == TableOBJECT.NAME);
    if (objectInDB != null) // UPDATE
        entities.TABLEA.ApplyCurrentValues(TableOBJECT);
    else // INSERT
        entities.TABLEA.AddObject(TableOBJECT);
}
entities.SaveChanges();
```

(I'm assuming that `NAME` is the primary key property of your `TableOBJECT` entity.)

Comment: So whats the difference between `Single` and `SingleOrDefault`?

Comment: Single checks if a query has only one result. If there is no result Single will throw an exception. SingleOrDefault checks for one result, if the query is empty it will return the Default value (most of the time NULL). So use Single when there should always be one result. Use SingleOrDefault when it's possible that there no result at all.

Comment: so it took me sometime to get to where I could use this and it's great except when it has to add more then one thing I get an exception from the DB complaining about not having unique keys. Ideas?

Comment: @Slauma: here's the exception it's on
`entities.SaveChanges();`
"**InvalidOperationException**
The changes to the database were committed successfully, but an error occurred while updating the object context. The ObjectContext might be in an inconsistent state. Inner exception message: AcceptChanges cannot continue because the object's key values conflict with another object in the ObjectStateManager. Make sure that the key values are unique before calling AcceptChanges."

Comment: I looked into it's a first chance exception and from what I can tell that means it could cause an exception later but didn't just now. So I'm catching it, ignoring it and everything keeps working fine. Does this sound safe or should I actually figure out how to stop it?

Comment: @Dan: Do you supply the key properties manually to your entities or are they autogenerated in the DB? The exception means that there are two or more entities in the context which have the same key value after saving the changes to the database.

Comment: When adding records I don't do anything because the primary key needs to be generated in the DB. It's an Int in my entity and I think it defaults to 0 which might be where the problem stems from. But the DB is smart enough to understand it needs to (re)assign a real primary key and does for these records.

Comment: @Dan: You should possibly create a new question about the problem and show the code you are exactly using. For autogenerated keys I cannot see where this exception could come from.

Comment: @Slauma As far as I'm concerned this is the correct answer and from further investigation I figured out the exception is coming from a back-end tool used to talk to the DB. I feel that the tool is throwing the exception wrongly and so thank you for your help. And I'll bring up the issue with the tools company.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to keep track of what is new and what is modified. If you do that, that the two code examples you provided are going to work.
A simple workaround which I used is to check if an entity's primary key property is set to anything. If it is set to a value, then that is an updated object, otherwise it's new.

Another solution would be to use Entity Framework's Self Tracking Entities, but I do not think that's the right direction to go in a web application (maybe it is in a distributed WCF app).